# AVSpeechSynthesizer volume too low

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create an app with Swift.

I integrated correctly speech-to-text and text-to-speech: my app works perfectly. You can find my project [here](https://github.com/nomercy89/speech-to-text/blob/master/MyStats/ViewController.swift).

After speech-to-text, the app makes an http request to a server (sending the text recognized) and the response (It is a string, i.e.: "Ok, I'll show you something") is reproduced vocally from text-to-speech. But, there is a big issue and I can't solve it.

When the app is reproducing the text vocally, the voice is too slow, as if it were in the background, as if there was something to be reproduced more important than the voice (actually nothing).

Debugging, I discovered that the issue starts using audioEngine (AVAudioEngine) inside the function `recordAndRecognizeSpeech()`. Running the app without using this function and playing a random text it works like a charm.

So, in my opinion when the app is reproducing the text vocally, it thinks there is still active audioengine, so the volume is very slow.

But, before reproducing the text, I called these functions (look inside ac function, line 96):

```
  audioEngine.stop()
  audioEngine.reset()
```

How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT:**
I found a partial solution. Now before the app plays the text vocally my code is:

```
   audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
    audioEngine.stop()
    audioEngine.reset()
    recognitionTask?.cancel()
    isRecording = false
    microphoneButton.setTitle("Avvia..", for: UIControl.State.normal);
    do {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)
        try audioSession.setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)     
    } catch {
        print(error)

    }
    make_request(msg: self.speech_result.text!)
```

The function .setCategory works and the volume is like the default one. When I try to recall `recordAndRecognizeSpeech()` function, the app gives me this exception:

`VAEInternal.h:70:_AVAE_Check: required condition is false: [AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:910:SetOutputFormat: (IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(hwFormat))]`
This exception is caused by `.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)`, it should be .playAndRecord, but with this value the volume returns to be low.

Comment: I believe you mean that the volume is **low**, not slow - is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
let speaker = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

func say(text: String, language: String) {
    // Start audio session
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.default)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
    } catch {
        return
    }
    
    if speaker.isSpeaking {
        speaker.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
    } else {
        myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
        myUtterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
        myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: language)
        myUtterance.pitchMultiplier = 1
        myUtterance.volume = 2
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.speaker.speak(myUtterance)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The docs for AVSpeechUtterance.volume say "Before enqueing the utterance, set this property to a value within the range of 0.0 for silent to 1.0 for loudest volume. The default value is 1.0. Setting this after enqueing the utterance has no effect."

Answer (score -1):

**Try This** . 
set rate for play speedly

```
 var speedd = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
 var voicert = AVSpeechUtterance()
 voicert = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon")
 voicert.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
 voicert.rate = 0.5
 speedd.speak(voicert)
```

Comment: you want to change   voicert.rate = 0.5 this like voicert.rate = 2.0 etc...